# How to mock LiveData in mockk kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mockk, mutablelivedata

Hey I am using mockk library in my project. I am trying to mock MutableLiveData, but it always give me null value. Can someone guide me how to do in proper way.

Suppose I have one function

```
var dataLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
 val currentDeviceTypeLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

internal fun handleDataResponse() {
        dataLiveData.postValue(true)
        currentDeviceTypeLiveData.postValue(true)
}
```

I am trying to test

```
@Test
fun `handleDataResponse - Handle connection success `() {
    // STUBBING
    // EXECUTION
    viewModel.handleDataResponse()
    // VERIFICATION
    assertEquals(true, viewModel.dataLiveData.value)
    assertEquals(true, viewModel.currentDeviceTypeLiveData.value)
}
```

It gives me this when I run the test

```
Expected : true
Actual   :null
```

**dependencies**

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.12.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tips that helped me:

1. run your test in runBlockingTest
2. create variable for live data before sending in assert function

```
@Test
fun `handleDataResponse - Handle connection success `() { 
 runBlockingTest{

    // STUBBING
    // EXECUTION
    viewModel.handleDataResponse()
    val dataLiveData = viewModel.dataLiveData.value
    val currentDeviceTypeLiveData = viewModel.currentDeviceTypeLiveData.value
    // VERIFICATION
    assertEquals(true, dataLiveData)
    assertEquals(true, currentDeviceTypeLiveData)
 }
}
```

3. Add this in test Class

```
@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

4. Declare
   `private val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()`
   and Add this in setUp()
   `Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)`
5. Add this in tearDown()
   `Dispatchers.resetMain()`
6. Add this before your test class declaration
   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi